# Which freezer gains the least amount of thermal energy in this time and why?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Two freezers X and Y are identical except that one has a door opening at the front and the other has a door opening at the top.

Both doors are the same size and are opened for the same amount of time.
Which freezer gains the least amount of thermal energy in this time and why?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this so far?

Comment: I think the freezer which has  door opening at front gains the least thermal energy because warm air falls and cold air rises but  I am not sure.

Comment: You might want to check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGAhWgkKlHI

Answer (score 1):

> ...warm air falls and cold air rises...

you've got that backward. Cold air is more dense than warm air.

If the freezer is surrounded by warmer air; then when you open the front-facing door, the cold air in the freezer will quickly spill out onto the floor and be replaced by warmer air from the environment.  If you continue to leave the door open, there will be a continuous flow of air: The room air entering at the top will continuously be cooled by contact with the cold walls and cold food, and it will continuously sink to the floor and replaced by more warm air from the room.

If the surrounding air is *still*, and if you gently open the top-facing door, then not much air will move because the vertical walls of the freezer will stop the cold, dense air from "falling" out. Just like how the water won't spill out of a covered bowl if you lift the cover off.

---

Added:

Heat transfer by natural flow of the air is called [*convection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection). As mentioned above, there won't be much convection when you open the top-facing door, but opening that door *will* allow heat to enter by [*radiation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation) and, to a lesser extent,* by [*conduction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction).

* Still air actually is a poor conductor of heat.